# I have an app made in Express. Is there a way to use the views in Cordova?

Tags: cordova, express

As the question, I have an Express app with views that render based on passed data? Is there any way we can use these views with Cordova? Like an app that renders a WebView inside the app..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use in app browser plugin.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Alternatively you can use

```
window.open("https://www.example.com");
```

Hope this helps. :)